# react-native fetch undefined on button press

Tags: react-native

I have a function when I press a button to get data
however my app is erroring on fetch undefined

```js
 async doNext() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json`);
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        console.log(jsonData);
        
}
```

error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)
undefined is not a function evaluating 'fetch'('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json'))
```

I also tried to write it like this:

```
 doTest = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json`);
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        console.log(jsonData);


}

 doNext() {
   this.doTest();
}
```

but got the same error

how do I make 'fetch' defined, if I console.log(fetch) I get undefined

Comment: I have started a new project and this code works, how can I find out what is throwing off my fetch command in my old project?

Answer (score 1):

found the problem in my code

```
self = this;
```

missing let or var, this was in index.android.js this line alone broke everything no warnings appeared for this